# Can we use another word instead of "Might" in Optative Sentence in Narration?

Tags: word-usage

For example 
They said,"long live our democracy!"
They wished that their democracy might live long !
whether the word 'might' in this sentence  is representing possibility?

Comment: Didn't the source of your examples explain what optatives are all about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite complicated.

It does mean possibility, but not in the sense that people usually use *might* today.

In current speech, *might* is used as a tentative possibility ("I don't know if it is, and I don't think it is very likely, but it is possible", or something like that). It tends to be more doubtful than *may*.

This is an older use, where *might* is formally the past tense of *may*: past, because it is indirect quotation: "May our democracy live long" -> "They wished that their democracy might live long".

The sense of "possibility" here is not "it is possible", but "we want it to happen [but cannot be sure it will]".

*May* is still used in this way, though it's a bit literary; but *might* is not often used as its past tense.